# Apply awk filter for loop of variable length

Tags: awk

I'm trying to write a script to filter tables in bash (with `awk`) taking account different fields for each one.

I've got an idea but I'm a bit lost with the code:

1. Create a variable with columns to filter, e.g. `foo="22 24 29 33"`.
2. Create a (tricky) loop to generate an string with variables to add to `awk`, i.e.: `aux=$(for i in $foo; do echo '-v col$i="$(echo $i)"'; done)`. Output should be like this (this is my first doubt): `-v col22="22" -v col24="24" -v col29="29" -v col33="33"`.
3. And finally, `awk $aux 'col24 < 10 ... {print}'`

But I'd like to optimize (or maybe there's another simpler way to do this) it for doing this process automatically for different fields and a number of fields. Whatever idea will be welcome! Thanks!

**EDIT**: I'd like consider all fields simultaneously and not one by one, something like this `awk '$22 >= 5 && $24 >= 5 && $29 >= 5 && $33 >= 5 {print}' file`... @kvantour response it's correct but I didn't explain enough the question and the output. Any additional help, please?

Comment: First of, be aware you have to use the `$` operator to reference a field. So it is `$col24 < 10 { print }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way:

- Create a bash variable just like your `foo`.
- Pass that full string to Awk, and let awk do the rest:

This gives:

```
awk -v fields="$foo" 'BEGIN{split(fields,f)}{ for(i in f) if ($(f[i]) < 10) print }' file
```

Of course you can now do various conditions:

assume `bar` is the condition list

```
$ foo="22 24 29 33"
$ bar="10 20 30 40"

$ awk -v fields="$foo" -v conditions="$bar" '
     BEGIN{split(fields,f); split(conditions,c)}
     { for(i in f) if ($(f[i]) < c[i]) { print; next } }' file
```

*note:* as your question is a bit ill-defined I was unaware what your script really has to do. Nonetheless, I hope this gives you an idea.

**after edit**

```
$ awk -v fields="$foo"  '
         BEGIN{split(fields,f)}
         { a=1; for(i in f) a = a&& ($(f[i]) >= 5) }
         a' file
```

Comment: Hi @kvantour, I've edited the question, you're right, it wasn't enough clear... could you help me with the new EDIT, please?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess that changing `&&` by `||` makes that the `awk` command something like this: `awk '$22 >= 5 || $24 >= 5 || $29 >= 5 || $33 >= 5 {print}' file`, right?

Comment: @jgarces Yea but for the or you need to set `a=0`

Comment: Ok, I thought I understood the code but not totally... could you explain it a bit, if you don't mind, please? And I've another question, the default character for `split` is space? Because I get different results depending of `split(fields,f)` or `split(fields,f, " ")`. Thanks!

Comment: The logical AND is only true if all are true. For this reason, `a` has to be initialized to `1` If it would be `0`, `a` could never turn into true. The opposite accounts for the logical OR. it can only be false if all are false. This means that `a` has to be initialized to `0`. If it would be `1` it would always be `1`.

Comment: @jgarces regarding `split`, it is unclear to me what the content of `fields` is. Please ask this in another question.

Comment: I'm reviewing the output after using this `awk` command (`{a=1; for(i in f) a = a&& ($(f[i]) >= 5)}`) and I think it's not working totally well... it filters **whatever** row with a zero value instead of a row where **all** fields values are equal to zero, I mean: it seems that's doing iteratively `$(f[i]) >= 5` and not `$22 >= 5 && $24 >= 5 && $29 >= 5 ...`. Maybe I doing something wrong, any idea, please?

Comment: @jgarces This line will select all lines where ALL the selected fields are all bigger then 5. So if it contains any number smaller then zero, it will not print it.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to say I used again this command to filter the matrix but changing 5 by 0 (`$(f[i]) > 0`)in order to not print those rows with all values equal to zero... and it's deleting the row when it finds a only zero and the rest of values are higher than zero. Sorry if I'm a bit stubborn, thanks again!

Comment: @jgarces that awk-line will select all lines where the selected fields are zero or more. So it will not print any line which has a negative number.